# How to add child tags to a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I'm trying to fill an array with all direct child elements of a div.
example:

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <a></a>
</div>
```

should result in an array containing `span` and `a`

How Would I achieve this?

I tried `var elements = $('.thediv').children();` but that doesn't seem to work.

Also how Would I then use that information for this kind of function?:

$("element1","element2","element3") depending on the result of the array?

Really thank you for your help! I am kind of lost with this thing

Note: I'm using zepto.js which has a similar syntax to jquery but misses a lot of functions so that might be a problem but I am also happy with solutions using jquery syntax because it should work pretty well :) https://github.com/madrobby/zepto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the tags *into* the array, you could easily use, with jQuery (though I'm unfamiliar with [zepto](/questions/tagged/zepto)):

```
var elementsArray = [];

$('div').children().each(
    function(i){
        elementsArray.push(this.tagName.toLowerCase());
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ybgq2/).

And to use them, you can try:

```
for(i=0;i<elementsArray.length;i++){
    $('div').find(elementsArray[i]).css('color','red');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ybgq2/1/).

Although this simply uses the `tagName` of each element, so if there is more than one `a` within the relevant element *all* elements matching the selector, effectively `$('div').find('a')` in this case, will be targeted by the selector.

The above caution seems to be discounted through use of a more complicated selector, and behaviour, and allows for each element to be iterated over one at a time, though I can't help but feel it's a little more complex than it needs to be:

```
var elementsArray = [];

$('div').children().each(
    function(i){
        elementsArray.push(this.tagName.toLowerCase());
    });

for(i=0;i<elementsArray.length;i++){
    $('div')
        .find(elementsArray[i])
        .not('.edited')
        .eq(0).css('color','red')
        .addClass('edited');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ybgq2/12/).

*Sigh*, I'm an idiot. The final iteration of this is below, which reduces the complexity somewhat, and allows for proper iteration over each element according to their position in the array:

```
var elementsArray = [];

$('div').children().each(
    function(i){
        elementsArray.push(this.tagName.toLowerCase());
    });

for(i=0;i<elementsArray.length;i++){
    $('div')
        .children()
        .eq(i)
        .css('color','red');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ybgq2/14/).

Having said the above, though, if you want to "target all elements within," why not simply target those elements with:

```
$('div').children();
```

Which will select, and target, each direct child of the `div` element without first holding them in, or having to hold them in, a user-created array variable.

Comment: that looks nice. I think that will work in zepto too :). Do you know about the 2e part? How would I use the tags in that array and add a style to them for example?

Comment: I was adding that as you commented, please see the edit. Though it comes with a caution.

Comment: that is exactly what I want. To target all elements within :). The content varies and that why I need to check :).

Comment: the elements I want to target are not in the same element where I select the elemts so $('div').children(); would not work. But you are right and awesome you've put so much work into this :D

Comment: That makes sense, then; and you're quite welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

$("div").children().toArray();

http://api.jquery.com/toArray/

> $("element1","element2","element3")

Does this mean you want to use the array as a jQuery selector? Or you really want the tag names?

Comment: Ahh, ok! Saw it tagged with jQuery and ignored the zepto part :)

Answer (score 0):

Each DOM node has a `childNodes` attribute, which is a [NodeList](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/quickref/obj_nodelist.html) containing all the direct descendants of the node in question.

Comment: ...which in turn is a `Array.prototype.slice.call(list);` call away from being an array.